# WCF Data Service authentication

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

-Is it possible to secure a WCF Data Service by using certificate-based authentication ?

-Is there a resource that describes this process ?

-Can we use Message security with a WCF Data service ?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to use WS-* bindings to get message level security.  Make sure you client can consume WS* standards. I think it is supported in .NET 3.0 and higher.  Silverlight does not support this.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to all your questions is "yes". Below is a very informative link provided by the Patterns and Practices team at Microsoft to accomplish exactly what you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949005.aspx

Comment: I followed the tutorial but keep getting an exception when trying to hit the service : "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied"

Answer (score 2):

Certificate based Authentication can be done like this:

Server side:

```
public class ODataService : DataService<Database>
    {
        public ODataService()
        {
            ProcessingPipeline.ProcessingRequest += ProcessingPipeline_ProcessingRequest;
        }

        void ProcessingPipeline_ProcessingRequest(object sender, DataServiceProcessingPipelineEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate.IsPresent)
            {
                throw new DataServiceException(401, "401 Unauthorized");
            }

            var cert = new X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);
            if (!ValidateCertificate(cert))
            {
                throw new DataServiceException(401, "401 Unauthorized");
            }

            var identity = new GenericIdentity(cert.Subject, "ClientCertificate");
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }

        private bool ValidateCertificate(X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            // do some validation
        }
```

Client side:

Create a partial class for your database service reference (DataServiceContext)

```
public partial class Database
{
    // ref: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0aa2a875-fd59-4f3e-a459-9f604b374749/how-do-i-use-certificate-based-authentication-with-data-services-client?forum=adodotnetdataservices
    private X509Certificate clientCertificate = null;
    public X509Certificate ClientCertificate
    {
        get
        {
            return clientCertificate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                // if the event has been hooked up before, we should remove it
                if (clientCertificate != null)
                {
                    SendingRequest -= OnSendingRequest_AddCertificate;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // hook up the event if its being set to something non-null
                if (clientCertificate == null)
                {
                   SendingRequest += OnSendingRequest_AddCertificate;
                }
            }

            clientCertificate = value;
        }
    }

    private void OnSendingRequest_AddCertificate(object sender, SendingRequestEventArgs args)
    {
        if (null != ClientCertificate)
        {
            (args.Request as HttpWebRequest).ClientCertificates.Add(ClientCertificate);
        }
    }
```

Use it like this

```
        Database db = new Database(new Uri(service));
        db.ClientCertificate = CertificateUtil.GetCertificateByThumbprint(StoreName.My,
                                                                          StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                                                                          "<a thumbprint>");
```

Private key stored on client computer, public key stored on server in Local machine/Trusted Root CA

Remember to require/negotiate client sertificate for this Site in IIS.

(Tested on WCF Data Services 5.2, VS 2012)